# How do I create a layout similar to the one from allwomenstalk.com?

Tags: css

[allwomenstalk](http://allwomenstalk.com/) has a very interesting layout. The posts are using absolute positioning.

My question is: How is the positioning calculated. The elements have text that forces some blocks to be bigger. However, the layout is ready right from the start, the site knows exactly where to place the next column.

Also, I'm wondering if there is a better way to achieve this, maybe with display table-cell or something like that.

Comment: This solution is not CSS-only. They calculated and set the positions (pixel coordinates) via script. -- In my opinion it's better to use a column layout with divs.

Comment: I'm still wondering how to do this without javascript :-?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they're using http://masonry.desandro.com/